# Lemma 5.3.6 in Bruns and Herzog, Cohen-Macaulay Rings

Tags: commutative-algebra

In the picture we discuss the Stanley-Reisner ring over a simplicial complex $\Delta$.

[image]
[image]

I do not understand the steps "(i) implies" and "(ii) implies", maybe I do not catch how to translate the complexes language into the element language. For example, which element in the $F$? Please help.

Comment: I try to from a$_i$>0 get v$_i$>0, but l maybe not positive. And I do not know how to show an elemant in the F.

Comment: The elements of $F$ are the vertices of the complex whose corresponding variables appear in $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F=\operatorname{supp}(x)$ and $\operatorname{supp}(x)\cup\operatorname{supp}(v)=\operatorname{supp}(xv)$; $xv\ne0$ (in the Stanley-Reisner ring) is equivalent to $xv\notin I_{\Delta}$. If  $\operatorname{supp}(x)\cup\operatorname{supp}(v)=\operatorname{supp}(xv)\notin\Delta$ what can we say about $xv$?

$\deg v/x^l=a$ shows that $a_i=b_i-lc_i$ where $b_i$, resp. $c_i$ is the degree of variable $x_i$ in $v$, resp. in $x$. If $a_i<0$, then the variable $x_i$ appears necessarily in $x$ otherwise $c_i=0$, and thus $a_i\ge0$. Conclusion: $F\supset G_a$.

$a_i>0$ implies $b_i>lc_i$ and since $l\ge0$ and $c_i\ge 0$ we get $b_i>0$. Conclusion: 
$H_a\subset\operatorname{supp}(v)$.

Comment: Thanks, F = supp(x) is helpful. In the middle part "by the definition of support", It seems that we can not avoid to use "l is not negative"...